Is a closed subscheme of a finite-type scheme also of finite type？
We're using the definition of a scheme of finite type as outlined in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. Alternatively, you can also consult the Wikipedia page on morphisms of finite type:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_finite_type
Question:  Is a closed subscheme of a finite-type scheme also of  finite type？
Clues and motivation: I am trying to solve the following exercise in the November 18, 2017 version of Vakil's book:

5.3 Properties of schemes that can be checked “affine-locally”-
Suppose $\mathrm{U}$ is an open subscheme of a projective $A$-scheme. Show that $\mathrm{U}$ is locally of finite type over $A$. If $A$ is Noetherian, show that $\mathrm{U}$ is quasicompact, and hence quasiprojective over $A$, and hence  of finite type over A.

So I want to ask the following more general question:
Is a closed subscheme of a finite-type scheme also of  finite type?
Any solutions, remarks, or clues are warmly welcomed. Feel free to add any necessary conditions.

Please use a more detailed citation than "GTM 52". Author name and book title are a better combination, for instance. I've made the upgrade to your post this time.

@KReiser  Thanks a lot!

Yes, this is true. This simply follows from the fact that closed immersions are of finite type and that the composition of two morphisms of finite type is again of finite type.
